# Total ordering does not return for expected output python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have an input that contains 6 people and each person holds name and number.
I am trying to write sorting function to sort them based on their number. If two numbers are same I am trying to sort them based on name.

To implement it, I use total_ordering. However it does not return the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
from functools import total_ordering


@total_ordering
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name=name
        self.number=number

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}, {}".format(self.number, self.name)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.number<other.number

    def __eq__(self, other):
         return (self.number==other.number and self.name==other.name) or self.number==other.number

    def __le__(self, other):
        return (self.number==other.number and self.name<other.name) or self.number<other.number

customList=[
    Person('object', 99),
    Person('michael', 1),
    Person('theodore', 21),
    Person('amazon', 21),
    Person('life', 42),
    Person('tree', 42)
]

a=sorted(customList)
print(a)
```

The code snippet returns `[1, michael, 21, theodore, 21, amazon, 42, life, 42, tree, 99, object]` however I expect for `[1, michael, 21, amazon, 21, theodore, 42, life, 42, tree, 99, object]`

Thank you.

Comment: Your `__lt__` only compares `number`, and only `__lt__` is used in `sorted`. You should use `return (self.number, self.name) < (other.number, other.name)`

Answer (score 1):

I would write

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return (self.number, self.name) < (other.number, other.name)
```

similarly for `__eq__` and `__le__`

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your definition. Instead of  (other.number, self.name) it should be  (other.number, other.name). In this way it works correctly.                                                                    
def __lt__(self, other):
    return (self.number, self.name) < (other.number, self.name)